# write web service response in to csv file in robot framework

Tags: python, csv, robotframework

I want to take web service response in to csv file. 
For eg :  This is the response.

```
<address><company>ABC</company><urban></urban>
<primaryaddress>ABCDEFG</primaryaddress><city>XYZ</city><state>WA</state>
<zip>11111</zip><zipplus4>8888</zipplus4></address>
```

How to get values for company, urban, primaryaddress, city, state, zip, zipplus4  in to the csv file ?

right now I am using substring as below:

```
    ${Company}  Split String  ${GetCAResult}  <company>
    Create File  ${EXECDIR}/file_with_variable.csv   ${GetCAResult.company}
```

doing substring for every value does not seem to be solution. is there any other way to get values ?

Comment: You've told us what you want, but you haven't asked a question. What part of the problem do you need help with? Do you need help parsing the xml? Converting it to csv? Writing to a file?

Comment: I want values like ABC for company in to csv file.

Comment: I got the response from csv file as written in the post and I want those response written in to csv file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [XML library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html) to parse the data. For example:

```
${GetCAResult}=  Get the data

${address}=  Parse XML  ${GetCAResult}
${company}=  Get element   ${address}  company
${city}=     Get element   ${address}  city
${state}=    Get element   ${address}  state

Create File  ${EXECDIR}/file_with_variable.csv   
...    ${company.text}, ${city.text}, ${state.text}
```

Answer (score 2):

As this is an xml string, you can use the [XML Library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html) to process the string.
In particular the section about [Parsing XML](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html#Parsing%20XML) should be of interest to you. It contains an example that you can adapt to your situation.